# Sending text to slack: R says it defaults to UTF-8 but umlauts are still not shown correctly

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, slack, slackr

I'm working with slackr to send automated text to a slack channel. That works perfectly on Linux. However, if I send the same message from my Windows PC there's a problem with umlauts.

```
> slackr_bot("äääää")
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
```

In slack:

```
<e4><e4><e4><e4><e4>
```

Comment: Note: you are not sending UTF-8 data. <e4> is in Latin1. As the warning tell you: please specify the encoding. Better to be explicit

Comment: So where do I do that? R Studio defaults to UTF-8, I've also tried to set my Windows 10 default to UTF-8 and tried to change the encoding for x

Comment: Help me I'm going crazy here 
> x <- data.frame("üüüüüü", "äääää", encoding = "UTF-8")
> slackr_bot(x)
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.

Comment: > slackr_bot("äääää", encoding= "UTF-8")
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.

Comment: Are you sure about "R Studio defaults to UTF-8" ? Could you save your file, and open in an other editor, where you can see and change encoding? Maybe R-Studio now is UTF-8, but your file was not saved as UTF-8

Comment: Hey, thanks for the questjon. Do you mind opening an issue for this on the slackr GitHub repo? This sounds like a bug to me, so if you open an issue I'll look into a fix. Thanks!